# For loop not incrementing consistently in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, for-loop, flash-builder

The following function is designed to create several arrays of student information. The studentList array is displayed with a comboBox with elements "All, A, B, C, D, etc.,". The comboBox is set to call this function on change. The default selectedIndex for the comboBox is zero, so on initial display it is set to "All" and all the students are listed.

The user selects "B" in the comboBox and only the students with last names that start with B are listed. The user then selects "Z" and only the Z students are listed. Great so Far.

If now the user selects "All", the list goes empty. Selecting "A" again and we get the A students. Select "All" we get nothing.

I put the "hit count" in there to better explain what is happening.

On the initial display the hit count displays 600 and the studentsAll collection size displays 600 which is, correctly, the total number of students in the list.

When a letter is selected the hit count correctly displays the number students now in the list and the studentsAll size is remains at 600.

When "All" is once again selected, however, the hit count goes to 1 and the list is empty. studentsAll size remains at 600.

What is wrong here. I do not see _index incrementing as it should, but only when selecting "All". It's as if the studentsAll.Length value is returning 1 instead of 600. But I checked and it is correctly returning 600.

"All" works once, but never again. While the method continues to work fine every time when filtering for a letter.

TIA for any help.

John

```
private function filterStudents(): void {
    studentsList.removeAll();
    studentsIDs.removeAll();
    studentsEmailpws.removeAll();
    studentspws.removeAll();

    var _studentNameFirstLetter:String;
    var _filterLetter:String = alphaFilterCombo.text;

    var _i:int=0;
    var _doAll:Boolean = alphaFilterCombo.selectedIndex == 0;
    var _doIt:Boolean = true;

        //note:studentsAll is an xmlCollection of all the students filled on startup
    for (var _index:int=0; _index < studentsAll.length; _index++) {
        if (!_doAll) {
            _studentNameFirstLetter = studentsAll[_index].name;
            _studentNameFirstLetter = _studentNameFirstLetter.substring(0,1);
            _doIt =  (_studentNameFirstLetter == _filterLetter);

        } 

        if (_doIt) {
            _i ++;
            formTitleLabel.text = "hit count = "+ _i.toString() + " studentsAll size = " + studentsAll.length.toString();
            studentsList.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].name, studentsList.length);
            studentsIDs.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].id, studentsIDs.length);
            studentsEmailpws.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].emailpw, studentsEmailpws.length);   
            studentspws.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].pw, studentspws.length);  

        }

    }   
}
```

Addendum: Code using built in filter function...

```
private function filterStudents(): void {
    var filterFunctionToUse : Function;
    studentsList.removeAll();

    searchedChar = alphaFilterCombo.text;
    filterFunctionToUse = studentLastNameFilter;    
    studentsAll.filterFunction = filterFunctionToUse;
    studentsAll.refresh();

    for (var _index:int=0; _index < studentsAll.length; _index++) {
        studentsList.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].name, studentsList.length);      
    }   
}

private function studentLastNameFilter(value : Object) : Boolean{
    return  (value.name as String).charAt(0) == searchedChar;

}
```

Addendum2: The following is the result method of the HTTPService that returns the students in a database that fills studentsAll...

```
[Bindable] private var studentsAll:XMLListCollection = new    XMLListCollection(); 
[Bindable] private var studentsList:XMLListCollection;   
[Bindable] private var studentsIDs:XMLListCollection;    
[Bindable] private var studentsEmailpws:XMLListCollection;
[Bindable] private var studentspws:XMLListCollection;

private function lookupStudentsSuccess(event:ResultEvent) : void { 
    var _studentsXML:XML = XML(event.result);   
    studentsAll = new XMLListCollection(_studentsXML.details);      
    studentsList = new XMLListCollection;
    studentsIDs = new XMLListCollection;
    studentsEmailpws = new XMLListCollection;
    studentspws = new XMLListCollection;

    for (var _index:int=0; _index < studentsAll.length; _index++) {
        studentsList.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].name, studentsList.length);
        studentsIDs.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].id, studentsIDs.length);
        studentsEmailpws.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].emailpw, studentsEmailpws.length);   
        studentspws.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].pw, studentspws.length);  
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little bit about how it was working, I think this will be a cleaner solution, using the built in filterFunction property.

```
import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;

private var searchedChar;
private var studentsList : ArrayCollection;
private var studentsIDs : ArrayCollection;
private var studentsEmailpws : ArrayCollection;
private var studentspws : ArrayCollection;
private var studentsAll : XMLListCollection;

private function filterStudents() : void
{
    var filterFunctionToUse : Function;
    var _doAll : Boolean = alphaFilterCombo.selectedIndex == 0;
    if (_doAll)
        filterFunctionToUse = null;
    else
    {
        searchedChar = alphaFilterCombo.text;
        filterFunctionToUse = aFilterFunction;
    }
    studentsAll.filterFunction = filterFunctionToUse;
    studentsAll.refresh();

    //note:studentsAll is an xmlCollection of all the students filled on startup

    for (var _index : int = 0; _index < studentsAll.length; _index++)
    {
        formTitleLabel.text = "hit count = " + (_index + 1).toString() + " studentsAll size = " + studentsAll.length.toString();
        studentsList.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].name, studentsList.length);
        studentsIDs.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].id, studentsIDs.length);
        studentsEmailpws.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].emailpw, studentsEmailpws.length);
        studentspws.addItemAt(studentsAll[_index].pw, studentspws.length);

    }
}

private function aFilterFunction(value : Object) : void
{
    return (value.name as String).charAt(0) == searchedChar;

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am fairly new to this so that your answer was very informative, but I was not able to get the filter to work. I get no hits. Does it matter that studentsList is an XMLListCollection instead of an ArrayCollection like you used in your code sample? I added the code, reduced to the bare essentials, that I tried based on your post to the end of my original question above. Can you see anything wrong with it.

Comment: I think I used xmllistcollection throw a breakpoint in the filterFunction.  Otherwise can you post your XML and loader.

Comment: I posted the method that loads studentsAll as addendum 2 to my original question. I appreciate your help on this. I would prefer to use the built in filter function if I can get it to work, but in the mean time I have reverted to my old code that did not work for All but did work for the filters. For the All functionality I am reloading the list from the database HTTPService.

Comment: Hi, no problem on the help, but can you post a little snippet of what the XML structure looks like, I can fully test out what I'm trying to propose if you give a little sample of what that would look like.  I'll proof it out real quick with my own made up structure and post it if I don't see a response here by the time I'm able to get it done.

Comment: Here ya go with 2 students...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<students>
<details>
<name>Abad,  Alyzza Korina (xxxxx@xxxx.com)</name>
<id>3014</id>
<emailpw>xxxx66@xxxx.com</emailpw>
<pw></pw>
</details>
<details>
<name>Abanto,  Lisa Marie M. (yyyyy@aol.com)</name>
<id>3011</id>
<emailpw>yyyyyy@aol.com</emailpw>
<pw></pw>
</details>
</students>